# Error running sonar: Unsupported Java version for PMD: 17

Tags: sonarqube, java-17

SonarQube version: 8.9.9
Configured Java source version: 17
Execute PMD 6.10.0
sonar.version: 3.9.1.2184

```
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
```

```
<build>
...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.sonarsource.pmd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sonar-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            
    </plugins>
</build>
```

See error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Java version for PMD: 17

Updated latest sonar version